# How to write domain filter onchange function for one2many field in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

In the following case I have written **def onchange_insp(self, cr, uid, ids, folionum,context=None)**  function  but at **inspec_type** in  **'feedback.tree'** is not working properly.

```
    from openerp.osv import fields, osv
    from openerp import api
    import logging

    class feedback_form(osv.Model):
        _name = 'feedback.form'

        _columns = {
            'company_id111': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Substation', required=True),

            'folionum' : fields.many2one('calendar.event','Maintenance ID',),
            'folio_number' : fields.many2one('asset.asset','Folio number',),
            # this field is filtering properly
            'inspec_type' : fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','Inspection Type',),

            'frequency' : fields.char('Frequency'),
            'shutdown' : fields.char('Shut Down'),
            #'insp_msr1' : fields.many2one('results.measure','Result',),

            'insp_rslt' : fields.one2many('feedback.tree','insp_rsltts','Inspection Result',),

        }


        def onchange_insp(self, cr, uid, ids, folionum,context=None):
            dids = []
            res = {}
            for record in self.pool.get('calendar.event').browse(cr, uid, folionum, context=context):
                dids = [x.id for x in record.inspection_name]
            dids1 = []
            for record in self.pool.get('calendar.event').browse(cr, uid, folionum, context=context):
                dids1 = [x.id for x in record.folio_num1]
            res.update({'inspec_type':[('id','in',dids)]})

            res.update({'folio_number':[('id','in',dids1)]})

            return {'domain':res}


    feedback_form()

    class feedback_tree(osv.Model):
        _name = 'feedback.tree'


        _columns = {
            **# How to do this for this field please reply me soon**
            'inspec_type' : fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','Inspection Type',),
            'valuess' : fields.char('Values/Results'),
            'insp_rsltts': fields.many2one('feedback.form','Result Id'),
            'insp_msr1' : fields.many2one('results.measure','Result',),
        }



        def onchange_measure(self, cr, uid, ids, inspec_type, context=None):
            dids = []
            for record in self.pool.get('asset1.inspection').browse(cr, uid, inspec_type, context=context):
                dids = [x.id for x in record.msr_insp]
            return {'domain':{'insp_msr1':[('id','in',dids)]}}

    feedback_tree()
```

Comment: are u working on api ?????

Comment: not yet till .. i am new for odoo

Comment: any solution for this

Answer (score 4):

With version odoo 10.0

> Solution applicable to one2many and many2many too :)

class res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

```
sb_sector_id = fields.Many2one('sb.business_sector',string="Business Sector" )
sb_categories_id = fields.Many2many('sb.business_categories','rel_sb_business_cates','confirm_id','status_id', string='Business Categories', required=False)

sb_activity_id = fields.Many2many('sb.business_activties','rel_sb_business_activties','confirm_id','status_id', string='Neclamenture of activities', required=False)


@api.onchange('sb_sector_id')
def onchange_sb_sector_id(self):
    return {'domain':{'sb_categories_id':[('sector_id','=',self.sb_sector_id.id if self.sb_sector_id else False)]}}
```

Mainly in return you had to write domain with field and give domain value.

```
return {'domain':{'sb_categories_id':[('sector_id','=',self.sb_sector_id.id if self.sb_sector_id else False)]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/what-should-onchange-methods-do-and-return-57760),

**Example**:

```
'insp_rslt' : fields.one2many('feedback.tree','insp_rsltts','Inspection Result', domain=[('valuess', '=', 'as u like string')])
```

Comment: please add code for this by last 2 days its freaking me please do share code

Comment: please share the code which works for me for detail i have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917081/how-to-get-domain-filter-for-following-situation-in-odoo

Comment: what u want please explain in detail dear

Comment: I have one inspection class in my own module .its many2one at calendar.event inherited module assigned with other fields . Now at feedback.form i wanted to have only those inspection which are assigned to folionum fields value ... everything is working only above pblm is der

Comment: please help me guys i have submit asap

Comment: wt i need to try same example is there bro

Comment: Hi, dear find in 8.0 have lost of example.

Comment: bro i am not getting so asked please help me

Comment: it would be great help to me

Comment: did you get anything about it